# How to erase the line drawn using Graphics in C#.net windows application

Tags: c#, winforms

We need to build an application that record our desktop.We draw lines on desktop to notify the user that we are recording his/her desktop.We want to erase the lines after recording complete.We draw the lines using Graphics in C#.net.Please check the code below,

```
IntPtr desktop = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);
using (Graphics g1 = Graphics.FromHdc(desktop))
 {
   Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Orange, 10); 
   Point pleftTop = new Point(2, 1);
   Point pleftBottom = new Point(2, 765);
   g1.DrawLine(blackPen, pleftTop, pleftBottom); 
   Point pTopLeft = new Point(1, 3);
   Point pTopRight = new Point(1356, 3);
   g1.DrawLine(blackPen, pTopLeft, pTopRight); 
   Point pRight1 = new Point(1356, 1356);
   Point pRight2 = new Point(1358, 1);
   g1.DrawLine(blackPen, pRight1, pRight2); 
   Point pBottom1 = new Point(1, 765);
   Point pBottom2 = new Point(1356, 765);
   g1.DrawLine(blackPen, pBottom1, pBottom2);

   string text = string.Empty;
   int screenHeight = Screen.GetWorkingArea(this).Height;
   int screenWidth = Screen.GetWorkingArea(this).Width;
   text = "Recording your screen & audio";
   int centerWidth = ((screenWidth / 3));
   int opacity = 255; 
   g1.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
   g1.DrawString(text, new Font("Arial", 15), new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(opacity,    Color.WhiteSmoke)), centerWidth, 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

The `Graphics.Draw...` functions replace the pixels. There is no way to undo that unless you either

- store the pixels that are being changed so you can reverse the drawing or
- draw the pixels on a copy of the desktop so you can revert to the actual desktop or
- overlay the desktop with a transparent surface and draw on that and remove the surface when it is no longer needed.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of storing all the pixels you could also just broadcast a message informing the desktop and all its child windows (i.e. everything) to repaint.  This is probably much better than my earlier suggestion, as you can paint whatever you like all over the desktop.

```
const int RDW_INVALIDATE = 0x0001;
const int RDW_ALLCHILDREN = 0x0080;
const int RDW_UPDATENOW = 0x0100;
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
static extern bool RedrawWindow(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr rcUpdate, IntPtr regionUpdate, int flags);
...
// Redraw the desktop and its children
RedrawWindow(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_ALLCHILDREN | RDW_UPDATENOW);
```

Answer (score 0):

One other option available to you is to use `ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame`.  It's quirkier and you can't draw text, but implementing this method is quick.  You don't even need a handle to the desktop.

Basically it draws a rectangle with an XOR operation so that if you call it a second time in the same location then the rectangle is erased.  Note that if any of the rectangle's pixels are modified between the first call and the second call then you'll get artifacts which will persist until the underlying window repaints itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool change = false;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (change)
        {
             InvalidateRect(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, true);
            change = false;
        }
        else
        {
            PaintLineToScreen();
            change = true;
        }


    }
    catch (System.Exception caught)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(caught.Message);
    }
}
```